# Whats the cheapest but strongest 4x8 I can use while only supporting the ends lengthwise of the board?

Tags: support

What I'm trying to do is basically make a shelf that is somewhat of a 2nd story in my rented self storage unit. I've done this before by bridging tall furniture w/strong boards. My unit is 12'x19'. I wanted to put a shelf (6ft tall metal restaurant or gondola shelving) on side of each storage in back against the wall & bridge them with something strong enough that I don't need to support the middle, should I need to park my car in there. I believe 4x8 is the largest piece you can get locally cheap. I hate any kind of pressed or particle board, because of how it falls apart the 1st time its moved or gets wet. I know there's an array of 4x8 made up of all types of materials I know nothing about and while researching them, I came across this website. What would be the strongest but cheapest 4x8 including what width I could get for this?  it would probally have a couple hundred pounds at very most, but also hold me (140#) up there organizing or walking to other side.
If anyone has any other ideas that are cheap/free, quick/simple& sturdy Im totally open to them. I thought a few  2x4s 10-12ft in length w/several cheap "shelving" boards perpendicular; possibly somn similar w/metal? i have drill & driver, but Im trying to keep it cheap and simple

thanks for taking the time to read this & offer me any suggestions.

Comment: Whoooooooa there that's a lot of wood!  I started writing based on "2x8" but you're asking about 4x8s?  Assuming your shelves are 2 feet deep you have an 8 foot span to bridge.  4x8s would hold a rather heavy load as long as there was sufficient overhang.  You can probably price it out with a grid of 2x4s, 2x6s or 4x4s with plywood over top. You have no specific requirements for fit, finish or treatment, so you have options to get the best price on the wood, which might help in the recent market.  Increasing height to width ratio of members will give you better rigidity with same wood mass.

Comment: That said, wood calculations are a pain in the butt for me even with online calculators, so I'll leave this for one of the car painters to answer.

Comment: Oh and what is the longest piece of wood you can physically get onto the shelf in the shelving unit?  If it goes too close to the roof or has a top shelf your span is limited.

Comment: Can you draw a diagram of what you had in mind? I am not sure you mean 4x8 as in a giant piece of lumber, or a sheet good e.g. plywood, or what.

Comment: When you say `4x8` do you mean a `4" x 8" x some length` piece of lumber, or are you referring to a `4' x 8' x some thickness` piece of plywood? A 4" x 8" piece of lumber, when sitting with the 8" vertical is A) _very_ expensive, and B) will support a fair bit of weight. A 4' x 8' sheet of plywood is quite likely what spans the joists under the floors of your house (below the carpet/tile/laminate flooring) and will also be strong, depending on how it's supported.

Answer (score 2):

There is no magic flat material that will have that kind of strength, short of some sort of honeycombed steel or carbon fiber, and I'm sure you don't have the budget for *that*.

Maybe you could use scaffolding planks, but again, budget.

### You'll need to frame that out with joists

And probably the cheapest will be conventional wood framing.

Since the critical dimension will be across the long length, you frame it out with 8 foot long "2x6" dimensional lumber oriented vertically for span strength.  I would follow the 16" spacing rule (though it will really be 15.5" center-center spacing), so that will be four 2x6 joists.   Two hug the edges of the plywood and two are spaced evenly between.

Now, we need something to prevent the joists from leaning sideways.  So some more 2x6 spacers go between the joists, wherever convenient.

Now, myself, I would screw the plywood to the joists with deck screws.  About every foot should suffice. You can nail it if you really want to, but you'll have an easier time disassembling the wood for reuse if you use screws.

The whole package will be 5.25" + the thickness of the plywood. So 3/4" plywood = 6" total height.